# How to show Jquery message in MVC from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am using MVC and I am checking the condition on the backend(controller).
I want to show message in a Jquery modal box which will be fired from the back end(controller).

Can anyone state me how to do this.

I have tried to use the following code but that is giving me some message: Invalid Argument.

```
string scriptstring = "$(function(){initializedialog();showDialog(\"" + "Please answer to all the Question." + "\");});";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "test", scriptstring , true);
```

Can you tell me how to use the above statement in MVC

Thanks

Comment: Try making use of Ajax.

Comment: I dont want to use it.

Comment: Pass some flag value in TempData For more information http://www.squaredroot.com/2007/12/20/mvc-viewdata-vs-tempdata/

Comment: **[Check same SO Query here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664193/what-replaced-clientscriptmanager-in-mvc)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so with ajax as ssilas777 has commented out.

use the following $.ajax code.

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'@Url.Action("Index","Home")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            //Here you will get the data.
            //Display this in your Modal popup
        },
        error: function(data){
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the controllers code .

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    //do some stuff
    string Message="your message here !";
    return Json(Message,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karthik I have already used this option but I was looking for for a method where I can show the message from the controller.

Comment: @Evostract  - Did u check **[here also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664193/what-replaced-clientscriptmanager-in-mvc)** ?

Answer (score 0):

In Controller, Set ViewBag Flag for it like :

```
 ViewBag.Login = "No";
```

Then in View Check on Document.Ready whether it is set or not and give your alert message there.

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    varifyForLogin();
});
function varifyForLogin() {
    if ('@ViewBag.Login' == 'No') {
        //Give your alert message here
        alert('Please answer to all the Question.');
    }
    document.getElementById('UserName').focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Use following code in script in view***

```
<script>
$.post("Home/Index", function(result) {
<br/>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;//result will be your message
<br/>
});
</script>
<br/>
```

***Controller:***

```
public ActionResult Index(){

    //do some stuff
    string msg="your message";
    return Json(msg,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```